# Convert spring security xml to annotation

Tags: java, xml, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to implement Spring boot security with a mongoDB with annotations. I've got most things down except that I need to translate this xml configuration to an annotated configuration:

```
<authentication-manager>
     <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

How to do this? And also, would it be that same to do just

```
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
```

Without the surrounding `<authentication-manager>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your implementation of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
}
```

Comment: Very many thanks, fixed my problem. Is this documented or should I've been able to figure this out by myself?

Comment: @PerEriksson, [AuthenticationManagerBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html) and [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-authentication-manager)